# why do link background overlap parent's sibling

Tags: html, css

I've made the following very simple HTML page

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    a {
        padding: 5px;
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
    }
    #header {
        background-color: orange;
        height: 50px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div> 
        <a href="/foo">foo</a>
        <a href="/foo">foo</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/whura34x/), the blue background of the links overlaps the orange background of their parent's sibling (the div with `id="header"`). How can I prevent this from happening without removing the links' padding?

Comment: Put `display: inline-block;` on the links. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/whura34x/7/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you try to add dimension to an inline element, some properties will
>   be applied, some properties will be partially applied and others will
>   not be applied at all. The most noticable properties are width,
>   height, margin and padding.
>   .
>
> While padding can be applied to all sides of an inline element, only
>   left and right padding will have an effect on surrounding content.

My solution:  Set the anchor links to `inline-block`.

[**Excellent Article - Link**](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/)

[**JSfiddle Backup Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/erv6Ls32/)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
#header {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 50px;
}
#nav {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="nav">
    <a href="#">foo</a>
    <a href="/foo">foo</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    #header {
        background-color: orange;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers. Please explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your anser.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/whura34x/3/

you need to make the anchor inline-block

```
a {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    display:inline-block

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Padding with inline elements without parents are weird :d

Try changing the display type with the anchor.

```
a{
    display:block;//you can also use inline-block without the float.
    float:left;
}
```